# Defining the GAL for Outlook 2007

Tags: exchange-2010, outlook-2007, exchange

I'm having an issue with running Outlook clients between domains.  Essentially, the computers that Outlook is installed on are joined to Domain 1.  They, however, must connect to Domain 2 which is over the Internet/Outlook Anywhere.  I'm trying to create a .prf file that can be deployed automatically across the domain.  We've already done this and ran into a problem: The GAL sometimes uses Domain 1 instead of 2.

Backstory: a division is being sold to a different company.  Domain 1 was the original domain; users have accounts and email addresses on Domain 1.  The Domain 1 email addresses are needed for the interrim until all data has been properly moved to Domain 2; the necessary data is being forwarded by Domain 1.  Domain 2 uses different usernames and email addresses; I need to automate giving Domain 1 users access to Domain 2 email.  This is working fine, except for the GAL.  Users still need to send email to both Domain 1 and 2, the wrong GAL causes routing issues for emails to Domain 1.

New domain is authed over Outlook Anywhere.  I've been turning off some auto-configure settings in registry, but results have been spotty.  What I think the issue is, is that the GAL is still sometimes being pulled via LDAP instead of what is defined in the Domain 2 autodiscover.xml file.  But, disabling LDAP authentication in Outlook doesn't seem to change anything.

Is there a way of forcing the correct GAL to be chosen when assigning an Outlook profile?  I'm an outside contractor to both companies, so I have no control over either Exchange servers.  However, this is a "desktop" issue, so it falls within my realm.  Both servers are Exchange 2010.  As far as I know, Multi-tenant and On-Premises modes are not in use.

Let me know what you think.  Thanks,

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing and is probably missing some relevant details. What do you mean "forcing the correct GAL"? The GAL doesn't have anything to do with domains. Are you referring to AD domains? Domain names that Exchange is authoritative for? Are you hosting multiple companies/customers on this Exchange server? Are you running Exchange in Multi-Tenant mode or On-Premises mode? If the latter are you using Address Book Policies?

Comment: Are you essentially saying you want to have your users log into the DC in the second domain as well? You're saying that their are two GAL lists, one in domain one and one in domain two, correct? You are also saying that you want your users to connect to the domain number 2's GAL instead of one, right?
I am a little confused when you say you don't have access to either Exchange Server, aren't the Systems Admin?

Comment: No, I mean the GAL. I don't have access to their Exchange servers as I'm an external contractor to the two companies involved. The GAL is actually interlinked with Active Directory pretty deeply, in ways I don't fully understand, and is normally generated based on which domain your Outlook logs into. No we are not hosting multiple domains on the Exchange server; yes to multiple divisions. No to Multi-Tenant mode and On-Premises modes afaik. Updated the question with more information.

Comment: As for the GAL having nothing to do with AD, that's wrong.  It does.  GAL basically tracks user accounts and distro-groups by OU.  It then determines if an email being sent is to a local account.  If it's local, it replaces the email address with the username in order to create a non-routable message.  Basically it creates a shortcut for all internal email.  The Outlook address book then keeps a local copy of this data so it doesn't constantly have to request the server for AD information.

Comment: A GAL/AL does not track user accounts. A GAL/AL can be filtered by OU (I believe), but a GAL/AL isn't involved in the message creation, modification or delivery process. Exchange 2010 can be installed in Multi-Tenant mode or in On-Premises mode but it can't be installed in neither mode. It's one or the other but it's not neither. If you could link to some documentation that supports your statements about the GAL/AL I'd like to read it because if it's the case then I'm seriously misunderstanding the GAL and AL's. Thanks.

Comment: Finding any information on how GALs work has been a pain.  I can only tell you what I've seen.  You put in an account such as Fname.lname@division.1 and it comes out as div1username@division.2.  The local address list modifies the sendto address to what it thinks is the local address.  If I then check MFCMapi, it tells me address list is looking  at the Division 1 OUs, not Division 2.  This would mean wrong GAL, correct?

As for Multi-Tenant or On-Premises, not sure what the definition would be.  Single domain, but remote servers.  This is On-premises? No external company hosts their mail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow, I thought I had updated this question a while ago.  This is one of those very specific questions that needs a good answer.  I wish I could give it, however I've changed jobs and with it I no longer have access to my notes on this issue.

What I remember doing was creating a .prf file which used custom environment variables for things such as the user's .pst to mount, their username, domain name, etc.  A script was set up on each user's desktop which created the environment variables used, as well as opened Outlook to load the .prf template that I had created.

I think part of this template changed the default address book to an OAB that would refresh on every startup, using Domain 2's autoconfig settings to determine how to update.  GAL via LDAP had to be disabled using GPO.  Wasn't pretty, but it lasted the 6 months it needed to during the transition.

OAB Updates:
https://www.howto-outlook.com/howto/oabupdate.htm

GAL Address Book GPO:
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/6bb9b40f-b794-41ce-93b4-711e77c53607/gal-default-adress-book-gpo
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/ff871432(v=office.14).aspx#Disabling_GALsync_GP

Possibly useful Profile Template (I don't have access to my original):
https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/131889-autoconfigure-outlook-with-script-prf-file-help

Something Newer than my solution that may help:
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/55e3fdd3-f5fd-4a28-ad29-8d2c41c640b4/gal-ldap-lookup?forum=exchangesvrgeneral